# How do you use for loop in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to minimize my code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I have two Sections 'A-M' and 'N-Z' as you can see below. I am planning to add several cities but it seems like my code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be very long.

What loop, and how do you implement it so that I don't have to add lots of else if.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"A-M";
            break;

        case 1:
            return @"N-Z";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        self.cityController.title = @"Bologna";
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        self.cityController.title = @"Florence";
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        self.cityController.title = @"Naples";
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        self.cityController.title = @"Rome";
    }

[self.navigationController pushViewController: self.cityController animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a different approach to how you have this coded up.  Because you're hard-coding these city names in there, you're going to make it much more difficult for you to add/remove/otherwise maintain your code.  At its most basic level, you could keep an array of the cities in your tableview.  This would allow you to change the data without changing your code.

Header:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cities;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

// other code

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *city = self.cities[indexPath.row];

    MyCityController *controller = // Init code;
    controller.title = city;

    NSLog(@"Selected city: %@", city);
}

// Other code

@end
```

Your datasource should be similarly implemented:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CELL_ID = @"CITIES";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.cities[indexPath.row];

    // Other setup code

    return cell;
}
```

You could lazy load them with hard coded values:

```
- (void)cities {
    if (_cities == nil) {
        _cities = @[@"Bologna", @"Florence", @"Milan", @"Naples", @"Rome"];
    }

    return _cities;
}
```

Or load them from a plist in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (!self.cities) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *cityDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        self.cities = [cityDict objectForKey:@"cities"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really new to this, so I still don't have full knowledge on what to use. Could you please enlighten me on how to do it? Pretty please.

Comment: @Jahm Personally, I'd ditch having the two sections.  You'll want to alphabetize them anyway and breaking them up doesn't buy your users anything.  Just have an alphabetized list of cities.  You can hard code those or store them in a plist with your app.

Comment: Quick question. is NSMUtableArray be fine instead of using NSArray?

Comment: @Jahm Use the appropriate collection for the job.  If you don't need to add or remove items at runtime, just use the immutable `NSArray`.

Comment: this is not related to the problem above. I had an error about [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Jahm your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: needs to return the number of items in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you fill in static array with all of this maybe something like this

```
NSArray *strings = @[ @[ @"City1", @"B", @"C" ], @[ @"D", @"E", @"F" ]];
```

After that just return this.

```
Strings[sectionindex][roeindex];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an appropriate data structure holding the data for each row in the table. In this case you should have an array of arrays of dictionaries (or something similar). The top level array would have one entry per section. The section array would have one entry for each row in the section. Each of those entries would be dictionaries or some custom object that represents the data for the row. This would include the title and anything else about the data for the row.

This data structure would be used for both 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and 'didSelectRowsAtIndexPath'. Based on the indexPath you extract the dictionary or custom class.

So your entire 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' becomes just a few lines of code.

Comment: Yes, if the data is in a plist then you get what I described when you load the plist into an array. As long as your plist data is setup just like you want it displayed in the table (two sections with two sets of rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case to avoid if-else.But are you displaying these city names in tableview and based on selection sending that name to cityController?If yes then there is no need to use switch case either because the way you are displaying those names using array, in the same you can send that name using indexPath.

Using switch case:

```
switch(indexPath.section)
{
  case 0:
        {
           switch(indexPath.row)
           {
             case 0:
              stmt;
              break;

              case 1:
              stmt;
              break;
           }
        }
  same as case0... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Wayne Hartman, you don't want a for loop you just want an array of all of your data. cellForRowAtIndexPath is called each time a cell is generated (or dequeued) and if you just tell it to load its title from your array like

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[citiesInItaly objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

it will be way more clean than hard coding your cell titles.